# Linq to SQL Nested Objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq, performance, linq-to-sql

I have a object called Category which has an Id, Name, and OwnerId. I then nest these to create Subcategories. If a category has an Owner Id it is a sub category. The number of subcategories is unlimited but each item can only have 1 parent. Simple enough.

My Issue is, I need to access a subcategory after loaded. How do I get the Owning category using Linq. I know the Owner Id but I dont know how many lvls deep the owner could be.

Basically I am looking for a way to get the Category or subcategory where the Id == X but this can live in a subcategory 6 levels or more deep.

I am trying to avoid a loop for each sub category in each sub category....

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to store/retrieve a tree hierarchy as explained in [this fogbugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/blog/post/Subcases-and-Hierarchy.aspx) blog post:

> Turns out there's a pretty cool
>   solution for this problem explained by
>   Joe Celko.  Instead of attempting to
>   maintain a bunch of parent/child
>   relationships all over your database
>   -- which would necessitate recursive SQL queries to find all the
>   descendents of a node -- we mark each
>   case with a "left" and "right" value
>   calculated by traversing the tree
>   depth-first and counting as we go.  A
>   node's "left" value is set whenever it
>   is first seen during traversal, and
>   the "right" value is set when walking
>   back up the tree away from the node. 
>   A picture probably makes more sense:
>
> [image]
>
> The Nested Set SQL model lets us add
>   case hierarchies without sacrificing
>   performance.
>
> How does this help?  Now we just ask
>   for all the cases with a "left" value
>   between 2 and 9 to find all of the
>   descendents of B in one fast, indexed
>   query.  Ancestors of G are found by
>   asking for nodes with "left" less than
>   6 (G's own "left") and "right" greater
>   than 6.  Works in all databases. 
>   Greatly increases performance --
>   particularly when querying large
>   hierarchies

[Here's another post](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database/2) going into more detail. It's written using `Sql` and `php` but I think you can get the gist of it and easily translate in Linq to Sql.

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL 2005 and up you can create recursive queries. In LINQ to SQL however, you are out of luck. Without restructoring the data in the database, there is no way you can traverse the tree in a single database call.

However... there is 1 workaround I can think of. When you are able to group all `Category` elements of a single tree (or a part of the tree) together, you can pre-load that part of the complete tree in a single statement. After that, you will be able to traverse that part of the tree, without triggering new calls to the database. It would look something like this:

```
// Load the category that will be used as starting point.
var subCategory = db.Categories.Single(c => c.Id == 56);

// Performance: Load the complete group in one go.
var categories = (
    from category in db.Categories
    where category.GroupId == subCategory.GroupId
    select category)
    .ToArray();

// Traverse the tree and get the top-most parent (if any).
var parent = subCategory.GetParents().LastOrDefault();

// Extension method to get the parents.
public static IEnumerable<Category> GetParents(
    this Category category)
{
    while (category.Parent != null)
    {
        // NOTE: cat.Parent will not cause a database call
        // when the Parent is already loaded by L2S.
        yield return cat.Parent;
        category = category.Parent;
    }
}
```

This of course will only work if you will be able to determine elements as a group. Whether this solution will be faster also depends on the size of the group. When the group of objects that you load (and don't use) is very big, it will actually slow the application down.